# Why does autofit row VBA code in Excel keep causing #value error in my formula?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, row-height

I have a concatenate based on offset array code that I'm using to combine data.

```
Public Function concatPlusIfs(rng As Range, sep As String, lgCritOffset1 As Long, lgCritOffset2 As Long, varCrit1 As Variant, lgCritOffset3 As Long, lgCritOffset4 As Long, varCrit2 As Variant, Optional noDup As Boolean = False, Optional skipEmpty As Boolean = False) As String

Dim CL As Range, strTemp As String

If noDup Then 'remove duplicates, use collection to avoid them

Dim newRow As New Collection

On Error Resume Next

For Each CL In rng.Cells
If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(CL.Text)) > 0 Then
    If CL.Offset(lgCritOffset1, lgCritOffset2) = varCrit1 And CL.Offset(lgCritOffset3, lgCritOffset4) = varCrit2 Then newRow.Add CL.Text, CL.Text
End If
Next

For i = 0 To newRow.Count
strTemp = strTemp & newRow(i) & sep
Next

Else

For Each CL In rng.Cells
If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(CL.Text)) > 0 Then
    If CL.Offset(lgCritOffset1, lgCritOffset2) = varCrit1 And CL.Offset(lgCritOffset3, lgCritOffset4) = varCrit2 Then strTemp = strTemp & CL.Text & sep
End If
Next

End If

concatPlusIfs = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Len(sep))

End Function
```

The code works great. It's not mine, but I tweaked someone else's code. The problem is that it will sometimes return a small amount of text and other times a large amount of text. I need the rows to autofit height. Before I started using the new concatPlusIfs formula, I used a code on the worksheet to autofit row height, but it cause a weird problem with the above code and only the above code and I can't find any mention of this type of problem. It works fine with all other arrays or non array formulas that I'm using. Basically what happens is that for a fraction of a second I can see the correct output in the cell and then I get #value!. I have no idea what's going on. I've tried autofit rows as a macro instead and it had the same effect. If I manually autofit the row everything is fine, but that's not a viable option.

Does anyone understand what would cause a problem like this? Or How can I fix it?

I'm not using any merged rows anywhere on the sheet.

Here are a few of the autofit strategies I've tried. One as a macro:

```
Sub AutoFit()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Rows.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Also as a code on the sheet,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
        Target.EntireRow.AutoFit 
    End Sub
```

And,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.Rows.AutoFit
'or be specific
Me.Rows("1:33").AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Any error if you comment out `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: I am not sure if it will help, but you can try replacing `.Text` with `.Value` because `.Text` can return `####` when the value does not fit

Comment: Changing all the .Text to .Value worked. I don't understand why based on your reasoning because it wasn't returning #### and worked without the autofit row, but it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely get `#VALUE!` error when your formula tries to convert the `###` from the `.Text` property to value. That is why you should use `.Value2` or `.Value` instead.